How did Kotzker Hasidim sound?
Did Kotzk hosids say אלוקייני instead of אלוקינו “ee instead of oo” sounds while davening? I know Gerer hasidim do and wanted clarification.
Thanks!

Do you mean elokaini with double yud after kuf rather than vav?

Yes so they aren’t saying oo at all just ee

They're from the Lithuanian portion of Poland, so it would be אלייקינו (with cholam sounding like a tzeirei)
